# Not able to execute Sahi Scripts from Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation, sahi

I'm trying to execute both sahi and selenium scripts using testng.xml build.xml . As both the scripts are configured in same project , I assumed its possible to trigger both scripts from Jenkins .

But now i'm able to trigger only Selenium scripts and not Sahi Scripts from Jenkins .

The exception thrown is :

```
error:_sahi.setServerVarPlain('___lastValue___Fri May 22 13:58:57 IST 2015', _sahi.loaded)
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'setServerVarPlain'
No trace available

<a href='/_s_/dyn/Log_getBrowserScript?href=null&n=-1'><b>Click for browser script</b></a>
    at net.sf.sahi.client.Browser.executeStep(Browser.java:320)
    at net.sf.sahi.client.Browser.executeStep(Browser.java:293)
    at net.sf.sahi.client.Browser.execute(Browser.java:262)
    at net.sf.sahi.client.Browser.fetch(Browser.java:708)
    at net.sf.sahi.client.Browser.navigateTo(Browser.java:193)
    at net.sf.sahi.client.Browser.navigateTo(Browser.java:181)
    at com.base.sahi.SonnetTestNGSahiBase.testSetup(SonnetTestNGSahiBase.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:653)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Also tried to google this error , but couldn't find any solution.

I using Selenium Webdriver , Sahi Pro(Trial version).

Comment: I would suggest using Sahi alone. Or if you think webdriver is the right way, use that. Using both will just create complications